# Passing props in layout.jsx in NextJS

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I'm using app router in NextJS-14 project.

I'm having layout.jsx file in which I have rendered header, footer and main content.

```js
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body className={`${raleway.className} w-screen`}>
        <StoreProvider>
          <Navbar />
          <PrivateRedirect privateRoutes={PRIVATE_ROUTES}>
            <div className='max-w-[1700px] mx-auto py-2'>
              {children}
            </div>
          </PrivateRedirect>
          <Footer />
        </StoreProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

What I want is to render the footer conditionally in child pages. Like in some pages, I don't want it, while in others it is required. So what I'm thinking is to pass some prop in `RootLayout` function which can be used to show the footer conditionally. But I'm not sure how to pass those props in `RootLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check NextJS Route Groups in docs
[Route Groups](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups)